# Simple dashboard application

Tags: javascript, dashboard, dashcode

I am trying to have some fun with dashboard widgets, so I tried a simple application :

> There will be a button over the widget which when clicked will open
>   StackOverflow website in safari.

To implement it, I tried this:

1. Created a custom dashboard widget.
2. Added a button to it from library.
3. Associated gotoStackOverflow handler with onclick event.
4. in body of function gotoStackOverflow, I wrote this code:

   window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/','Stackoverflow','width=400, height=300');

When I 'Run' the application I found no browser window appearing on click of the button.

Can anyone suggest me where I may be wrong or/ and some useful links to play with dashcode and dashboard widgets?

Comment: Maybe pop-ups blocked by your browser?

Comment: yes... it was blocked.. however it is still not working when I unblocked it:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following code to solve my problem:

```
function gotoStackOverflow(event)
{
    widget.openURL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
}
```

cheers... :)

Miraaj

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine, when I recreate it.  Maybe you have pop-ups blocked in Safari?

Comment: yes... it was blocked.. however it is still not working when I unblocked it:(

Comment: can we open the link in browser itself without displaying the pop-up window... like we have in google search widget?

Answer (score 1):

have you added

```
<key>AllowNetworkAccess</key>
<true/>
```

to the plist? if not the outside world will not be available.

Comment: can you suggest me how to edit plist file for a widget being developed in dashcode?

Comment: I got it... the check box - Allow Network Access was deselected in Widget Attributes ... but it is still not working :(